CAS'ing 32 lower bits of the 64 bit word in C++
I have a 64-bit shared variable, and one thread wants to CAS 32 lower bits of this word, while ignoring changes in higher 32 bits of this word. Is there a portable way to do it lock-free?
Does something like this work, or are there no ways around, that don't violate something related to strict-aliasing or C++ object model?:
union {
    std::atomic<uint64_t> desc;
    struct {
        std::atomic<uint32_t> ldesc;
        std::atomic<uint32_t> hdesc;
    };
} variable;

variable.desc = 0;
uint32_t x = 0;
variable.ldesc.compare_exchange_weak(x, 1);


Your code is definitely undefined behaviour, the usual approach to doing this sort of thing is CAS in a loop

but I don't want to spin for some extra time if there are some thread changing higher bits

There is no way to do this in the C++ memory/object model as currently specified in the standard.
Atomics in C++ only permit loading the whole underlying object's value. There are no primitives to load only part of an object's state (potentially with the exception of reading the object representation byte-by-byte which is currently underspecified).
That's true even for non-atomic access and even for scalar objects. Your example would have undefined behavior even if the members were non-atomic and the operation single-threaded. (And technically anonymous struct members are not valid syntax according to the standard.)
You can replace the object with a new one with a different type using std::start_lifetime_as and std::atomic_ref instead of std::atomic, but that must be synchronized externally between the threads and afterwards access as the old type isn't possible anymore.
That being said, compilers generally support the union type-punning in the non-atomic case for compatibility with C.
I am not entirely sure whether C permits the type-punning with atomic types and whether its memory model would allow what you are trying to do. You could ask the question for equivalent C code instead. If it is permitted in C, then it is likely that C++ compilers will support it for compatibility with C as well.
In either case, the behavior will be at best implementation-defined because it relies on representation choices of the involved types. It will also certainly be dependent on the involved atomics being lock-free, which is also implementation-defined (and can be checked with the corresponding members of std::atomic/std::atomic_ref).

"That being said, compilers generally support the union type-punning in the non-atomic case for compatibility with C" - type-punning a union is undefined behavior in C++, whether a compiler allows it or not. It is simply not allowed to access a field that is not the active (last written) field.

@RemyLebeau Yes sure, but when I say "support" I mean that as an additional guarantee to the ones the compiler has to make due to requirements of the standard. I am pretty sure current major compilers guarantee that this has the expected behavior. I think GCC at least even documents it.

@RemyLebeau: The Standard deliberately allows implementations to, as a form of "conforming language extension", define the behavior of constructs or corner cases which are "officially" characterized as UB.  Many type-punning constructs have defined behavior on clang and gcc when using the -fno-strict-aliasing flag because clang and gcc extend the semantics of language in such a fashion.

The Standard makes no distinction between implementations that would be capable of usefully and efficiently performing an atomic action on part of an object, versus those that would require the use of a loop to load the whole object, compute an updated version, and use a compare-and-swap to update it.  It is also ill-equipped to handle implementations that would on some types be able to perform some atomic operations, but not compare and swap, using native semantics (which would be one of the situations where partial updates would be useful).
If one needs to perform tasks for which the C11 atomic types would not be particularly suitable, platform-specific functions or intrinsics specified by the chip vendor may offer a better fit for what applications need to do.  If a platform offers an intrinsic or function to perform a 64-bit read which is guaranteed to have read both halves of the value without any intervening interrupts, its semantics, and ways it would interact with any natively-supported atomic operations, should be defined by the platform without regard for how or whether the Standard would impose any particular requirements.
